# Python Google Maps Driving Time

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to get driving time between two sets of coordinates using Python. The only wrappers for the Google Maps API I have been able to find either use Google Maps API V2 (deprecated) or do not have the functionality to provide driving time. I'm using this in a local application and do not want to be bound to using JavaScript which is what the Google Maps API V3 is available in.

Comment: Isn't this against the Google Maps TOS? I don't think you can just get driving time unless you are also displaying Google Maps to the user. (https://developers.google.com/maps/terms, section 10.1 g, "No Use of Content without a Google Map")

Comment: I never said I wasn't going to display a map, even though that's not what I need. If I wasn't what is an available alternative? Since I have no problem doing so, how can I solve my issue of finding something to work with python? Although I am currently pursuing Google Distance Matrix as a solution.

Comment: Because the API v3 is JS-only, any functionality must run through a web browser.. However, there are projects like pygmaps (https://code.google.com/p/pygmaps/) and py-googlemaps (http://py-googlemaps.sourceforge.net/) that act as Python wrappers for API operations, while running JS in the background.

Comment: Thanks. But pygmaps provides mapping functionality as far I can tell, without actually returning the data by itself as well. And I believe py-googlemaps I tried and is a wrapper for V2 which they arent providing api keys for anymore. My solution ended up being to use Google Distance Matrix by HTTP request and a JSON interpreter.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using URL requests to the Google Distance Matrix API and a json interpreter you can do this:

```
import simplejson, urllib
orig_coord = orig_lat, orig_lng
dest_coord = dest_lat, dest_lng
url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins={0}&destinations={1}&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false".format(str(orig_coord),str(dest_coord))
result= simplejson.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
driving_time = result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['value']
```

Comment: thanks this is great. I was wondering how can you change the mode of travel from driving time to cycle time for example?

Comment: @RegUser just change the `mode=driving` to `mode=bicycling` in the url.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it saves my day!!

Comment: @tsspires. Can you please include how to include the API key in your request? The code you provided won't work otherwise.

Answer (score 18):

```
import googlemaps
from datetime import datetime

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='YOUR KEY')


now = datetime.now()
directions_result = gmaps.directions("18.997739, 72.841280",
                                     "18.880253, 72.945137",
                                     mode="driving",
                                     avoid="ferries",
                                     departure_time=now
                                    )

print(directions_result[0]['legs'][0]['distance']['text'])
print(directions_result[0]['legs'][0]['duration']['text'])
```

This is been taken from [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python)
And alternatively you can change the parameters accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Updated the Accepted Answer to include the API Key and use a string for the addresses.

```py
import simplejson, urllib
KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

orig = "Street Address 1"
dest = "Street Address 2"
url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?key={0}&origins={1}&destinations={2}&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false".format(KEY,str(orig),str(dest))
result= simplejson.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
#print(result)
driving_time = result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text']
print(driving_time)
```

Comment: Hi, Any idea, how can this be iterated through the dataframe with 100's of records?

Comment: Does this take current traffic conditions into account because I've been running it for a day now where I get the driving time every 15 minutes and it has been the exact same time every time.  If it doesn't consider current traffic conditions, how can I get it to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/#unit_systems

Read the part about "Optional parameters." essentially, you add the parameter into your request in your url. So if you wanted biking, it would be "mode=bicycling." Check out the example towards the bottom of the link and play around with some parameters. Good Luck!