# Error while calculating distance matrix

Tags: python, urllib3, google-distancematrix-api

I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267807/python-google-maps-driving-time) post to calculate distance matrix
so this is the code snippet

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import quote  
import urllib.parse
import simplejson, urllib
import urllib.request
orig_coord = 19.12,19.45
dest_coord = 19.10,19.50
url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=' + urllib.quote_plus(orig_coord)+ '&destinations=' + urllib.quote_plus(dest_coord) + '&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false'
#url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins={0}&destinations={1}&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false".format(str(orig_coord),str(dest_coord))
#result= simplejson.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
result=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
driving_time = result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['value']
```

I had tried these two method(other one with comments)
but it never worked though,
now with these code I get the error

```
runfile('C:/Users/admin/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/admin/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-22-30ed5be6f1c7>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/admin/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/admin/.spyder-py3')

  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/admin/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 16, in <module>
    url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=' + urllib.quote_plus(orig_coord)+ '&destinations=' + urllib.quote_plus(dest_coord) + '&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false'

AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'quote_plus'
```

Comment: I think you have to replace the `urllib.quote_plus` calls with `urllib.parse.quote_plus` https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/urllib.parse.html

Comment: @Jose used `from urllib.parse.quote_plus import quote_plus `  but it gave error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib.parse.quote_plus'; 'urllib.parse' is not a package`

Comment: `from urllib.parse import quote_plus` works in python 3.1.6

Comment: Used the source code from [this](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python) and is working

Answer (score 1):

The `urlib` [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#module-urllib) states

> Note The urllib module has been split into parts and renamed in Python 3 to urllib.request, urllib.parse, and urllib.error.

So importing with `urllib`, `urlib.parse`, etc alltogether seems somewhat strange. `quote_plus()` should be in [`urlib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html). Did you try with that one?

Comment: I tried with `from urllib.parse import quote_plus `  but it gives error  `AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'quote_plus'`

Comment: @Domnick Something in your comment is strange. If `quote_plus` would not exist in `urllib.parse` you should get an error message like `ImportError: cannot import name quote_plus`. Your error message implies that you still try to call `urllib.quote_plus()`! You should remove the `import urllib` completely from your code.